# Restoring to another iPhone

Tags: restore

Do I need to reset my iPhone before restoring a backup of a different phone?  Eg swapping phones with partner. I have done both backups but not sure if I need to restore each phone first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General recommendation from Apple is to reset your device before restoring from backup.

[iCloud: Restore or set up iOS devices from an iCloud backup](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521)

> 3. Go to Settings > General > Reset, then tap “Erase All Content and Settings.”

[Restoring from an iTunes or iCloud backup when a later version of iOS is required](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203434)

> 5. Erase your iOS device: Tap Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings. After your device is erased, it restarts and you'll see the Hello screen in the Setup Assistant.
>
> Now you should be able to set up your device again, and select a backup to restore from.